# Cannot find module 'is-ci' when running cypress test

Tags: cypress

I want to run cypress tests using cucumber. When I hit Open Cypress from the feature file, I got an error
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:936
throw err;
^

```
Error: Cannot find module 'is-ci'
Require stack:
- D:\Repos\vt\node_modules\cypress\lib\util.js
- D:\Repos\vt\node_modules\cypress\lib\cli.js
- D:\Repos\vt\node_modules\cypress\bin\cypress
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\Repos\vt\node_modules\cypress\lib\util.js:21:14)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    'D:\\Repos\\vt\\node_modules\\cypress\\lib\\util.js',
    'D:\\Repos\\vt\\node_modules\\cypress\\lib\\cli.js',
    'D:\\Repos\\vt\\node_modules\\cypress\\bin\\cypress'
  ]
}
```

After googling a bit I found I need to run `npm install is-ci --save` but after that I got

```
npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency
npm WARN While resolving: eslint-config-airbnb-base@13.2.0
npm WARN Found: eslint@8.42.0
npm WARN node_modules/eslint
npm WARN   dev eslint@"^8.36.0" from the root project
npm WARN   14 more (eslint-plugin-import, eslint-plugin-prettier, ...)
npm WARN 
npm WARN Could not resolve dependency:
npm WARN peer eslint@"^4.19.1 || ^5.3.0" from eslint-config-airbnb-base@13.2.0
npm WARN node_modules/eslint-config-airbnb-base
npm WARN   eslint-config-airbnb-base@"^13.1.0" from @vue/eslint-config-airbnb@4.0.1
npm WARN   node_modules/@vue/eslint-config-airbnb
npm WARN 
npm WARN Conflicting peer dependency: eslint@5.16.0
npm WARN node_modules/eslint
npm WARN   peer eslint@"^4.19.1 || ^5.3.0" from eslint-config-airbnb-base@13.2.0
npm WARN   node_modules/eslint-config-airbnb-base
npm WARN     eslint-config-airbnb-base@"^13.1.0" from @vue/eslint-config-airbnb@4.0.1
npm WARN     node_modules/@vue/eslint-config-airbnb
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: mochawesome@6.3.1
npm ERR! Found: mocha@5.2.0
npm ERR! node_modules/mocha
npm ERR!   dev mocha@"^5.2.0" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer mocha@">=7" from mochawesome@6.3.1
npm ERR! node_modules/mochawesome
npm ERR!   dev mochawesome@"^6.2.1" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: mocha@10.2.0
npm ERR! node_modules/mocha
npm ERR!   peer mocha@">=7" from mochawesome@6.3.1
npm ERR!   node_modules/mochawesome
npm ERR!     dev mochawesome@"^6.2.1" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
```

Any help on what I need to do to run the cypress tests is appreciated.